# Owebia Shipping Module for Magento Issues

Tags: magento

Does anyone have experience with the Owebia Shipping method for Magento?

We've been trying to set it up for about 3 weeks now, and arent able to get help from the developers as they don't offer support.

1) I can't get Owebia to work with magento's shopping cart price rules for shipping.  I have a shopping cart price rule setup for FREE SHIPPING on specific attribute items, however, Owebia ignores this.  The cart rule displays free shipping properly with other shipping methods, but it doesn't seem to work with Owebia.  Owebia still shows the full shipping price based on its weight and ignores the rule.

2) I can't get Owebia's built in product.attribute.sku methods to work.  Basically, I have specific attribute products that are free shipping and can be bought along side regular products based on weight vs destination.  So I have no idea how to code that together with Owebia.  The method they provide in the Owebia documentation is absolutely useless as it gives no real examples of use.

Heres my current code (without any product.attribute rules):

```
{
"USAALLSMALLPACKET": {
    "label": "Small Packet Air (6-10 Business Days)",
    "shipto": "US",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 0.249:6.50, 0.499:8.75, 0.999:11.50}",
    "customer_groups": "NOT LOGGED IN,General"
},
"USAALLEXPEDITED": {
    "label": "Expedited (4-5 Business Days)",
    "shipto": "US",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 0:0, 0.499:14.30, 0.999:15.30, 1.499:16.30, 1.999:17.30, 2.499:18.30, 2.999:19.30, 3.499:20.30, 3.999:21.30, 4.499:22.30, 4.999:23.30, 6.499:27.30, 8.999:32.30, 10.499:37.30, 12.999:43.30, 14.499:48.30, *:87.00}",
    "customer_groups": "NOT LOGGED IN,General"
},
"CANADAAALLEXPEDITED": {
    "label": "Canada Expedited (2-7 Business Days)",
    "shipto": "CA",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 0.499:10.15, 0.999:11.15, 2.999:12.75, *:87.00}",
    "customer_groups": "NOT LOGGED IN,General"
}
}
```

What id like to do is be able to have it that if a product with attribute_set is  "Apple" is added to the cart that it wont charge for shipping for this product only, and only for certain countries.  In the above code; I have USA and Canada, I want it to be free shipping for USA only, for that specific product (not the whole cart).

```
product.attribute_set: name of the attribute set
product.attribute_set.id
product.attribute_set.*:
```

I dont know how to use the above 3 methods in any way.

Any help in regarde to this matter would be greatly appeciated

Answer (score 3):

Easy Damien, I thought I share my configuration with you and see if this put you on the right path.
For free shipping to work in Owebia, it must be qualify as free shipping by Magento first. 
Set this is up in shopping cart prices rules however you wish.
(i.e orders containing just apple -> Free shipping)
OR
orders where cart contains SKU=0002 only -> free shipping.
My point is, use magento to discern first whether a cart qualifies for free shipping, then use owebia to process the token

Once this is done, owebia identifies with the token "free shipping" as either true or false.

My configuration is as follows:

```
{
"base": {
    "type": "data",
    "fees": 5.95,
    "lowfees": 2.95,
    "zone2reg": "(/^IV.*|HS.*|ZE.*|KW.*|KA2[78].*|PA2[0123456789].*|PA3[0123456789].*|PA4[0123456789].*|PA6[0123456789].*|PA7[012345678].*|^PH1[789].*|PH2[0123456].*|PH3[0123456789].*|PH4[01234].*|PH[0123456789].*|PH50.*$/i)",
    "zone3reg": "(/^BT.*|IM.*|TR2[12345].*$/i)"
},
"free": {
    "description":"free",
    "label": "FREE SHIPPING (ON ORDERS > £100)",
    "shipto": "GB-{base.zone2reg}-{base.zone3reg}",
    "fees": "0.00",
    "conditions": "{cart.free_shipping}=='true'"
},
"zone2": {
    "description":"zone2",
    "label": "Highlands & Islands of Scotland",
    "shipto": "GB{base.zone2reg}",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 250[:{base.lowfees}+8, *:{base.fees}+8}"
},
"zone3": {
    "description":"zone3",
    "label": "Northern Ireland, Isle of Man & Isles of Scilly",
    "shipto": "GB{base.zone3reg}",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 250[:{base.lowfees}+10, *:{base.fees}+10}"
},
"regular48": {
    "description":"regular48",
    "label": "UK (Mainland exc. Northern Ireland)",
    "shipto": "GB-{base.zone2reg}-{base.zone3reg}",
    "fees": "{table {cart.weight} in 250[:{base.lowfees}, *:{base.fees}}"
}
```

}

the result is each of these methods is displayed if the conditions return true.
so in any scenario where cart.free_shipping == 'true' , the option "FREE SHIPPING" is given as a radio select.

Unfortunately, regular 48hour parcelforce is also displayed and the user must select FREE SHIPPING, though i belive FREE is the default since it is the first match. 
I tried setting the conditions of the parcelforce 48hr shipping to {cart.free_shipping}=='false' but didnt get the expected result so opted to have both methods displayed and free as default.

The "zone2reg" if youre wondering is a regular expression i wrote to filter certain postcodes for whom it turns out parcelforce is ruddy expensive to ship to ! :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Had the same issue and this was incredibly helpful.   Hard to find decent Owebia information out there.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree, Owebia is clearly massively versatile, but theres no real definitive way of using it ! 
Since the build concerned here, ive used it for several more complex configurations, but every time its been a bit guessy yknow!